# Attaching Visio files to TFS 2018 Wiki page

Tags: tfs

I have an on premise TFS. I would like to attach a Visio file to a wiki page. According to TFS documentation that file type was added to 2018. However, when attempted I get a message that the file type is not supported.

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you please provide the detailed steps to reproduce your issue? Tested on my side, the `*.vsdx` file can be attached successfully in TFS 2018 Wiki page.

Comment: I open a wiki page for editing. I can either attempt to attach the visio file (.vsd or .vsdx) by drag and drop or using the attach paperclip. in either case the wiki page responds with a pinkish banner indicating "The file type ".vsd" is not valid for attachments."  The version of TFS is Version 16.122.27409.2 which is 2018 the latest update I believe.

Comment: I tested on TFS 2018 Update2 (`Version 16.131.27701.1`), everything works as expected, can not reproduce your issue. So, obviously the version `16.122.27409.2` you used is not the latest update, please try to upgrade to the latest version then try it again. If still have the same issue, please  share the repro steps, capture screenshot is better.

Comment: Updated to TFS 2018 Update 2 and voila problem solved. Also addressed a couple of other items that I could find/make work. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's an issue for the `version 16.122.27409.2`.

The solution is upgrading to the latest update version of TFS 2018 (`TFS 2018 Update2, Version 16.131.27701.1`).